# longtable with note

Tags: tables

I need help to make longtable breakable with tablenotes in one line. in my example the notes are in 5 lines and there is a space between table and notes.

this is my code :

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem,booktabs,cfr-lm}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,threeparttablex}
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}
\makeatletter
\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\tnote{\alph*},ref=\alph*,itemsep=\z@,topsep=\z@skip,partopsep=\z@skip,parsep=\z@,itemindent=\z@,labelindent=\tabcolsep,labelsep=.8em,leftmargin=*,align=left,before={\footnotesize}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\newlength{\maxfigurewidth}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red},citecolor={red},urlcolor={red}}

\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \renewcommand\TPTminimum{\textwidth}
    %% Arrange for "longtable" to take up full width of text block
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        
\begin{longtable}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{7}{c} }
\caption{\label{tab:table1} longtable with tablenotes}\\
    \toprule
    year &$ x $ &Source&A&B&C\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{8}{r}{\textit{continued}}\\
    \endfoot  
            
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    %   \insertTableNotes  % tell LaTeX where to insert the table-related notes
    \endlastfoot
    2001& 0 &This work &3& 32& 10& 27\\
    2002& 1 &Other\tnotex{Calc1} &29&19&23& 27\\
    2003& 2 &Other\tnotex{Calc2} &330& 321& 40 & 202\\
    2004& 3 &Other\tnotex{Calc3} &336& 361&203 &60\\
    2005& 4 &Other\tnotex{Calc4} &360& 32& 118 &275\\
    2006& 5 &Other\tnotex{Calc5} &350& 432& 118 &275\\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    2001& 0 &This work &3& 32& 10& 27\\
    2002& 1 &Other\tnotex{Calc1} &29&19&23& 27\\
    2003& 2 &Other\tnotex{Calc2} &330& 321& 40 & 202\\
    2004& 3 &Other\tnotex{Calc3} &336& 361&203 &60\\
    2005& 4 &Other\tnotex{Calc4} &360& 32& 118 &275\\
    2006& 5 &Other\tnotex{Calc5} &350& 432& 118 &275\\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    2001& 0 &This work &3& 32& 10& 27\\
    2002& 1 &Other\tnotex{Calc1} &29&19&23& 27\\
    2003& 2 &Other\tnotex{Calc2} &330& 321& 40 & 202\\
    2004& 3 &Other\tnotex{Calc3} &336& 361&203 &60\\
    2005& 4 &Other\tnotex{Calc4} &360& 32& 118 &275\\
    2006& 5 &Other\tnotex{Calc5} &350& 432& 118 &275\\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    2001& 0 &This work &3& 32& 10& 27\\
    2002& 1 &Other\tnotex{Calc1} &29&19&23& 27\\
    2003& 2 &Other\tnotex{Calc2} &330& 321& 40 & 202\\
    2004& 3 &Other\tnotex{Calc3} &336& 361&203 &60\\
    2005& 4 &Other\tnotex{Calc4} &360& 32& 118 &275\\
    2006& 5 &Other\tnotex{Calc5} &350& 432& 118 &275\\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    2001& 0 &This work &3& 32& 10& 27\\
    2002& 1 &Other\tnotex{Calc1} &29&19&23& 27\\
    2003& 2 &Other\tnotex{Calc2} &330& 321& 40 & 202\\
    2004& 3 &Other\tnotex{Calc3} &336& 361&203 &60\\
    2005& 4 &Other\tnotex{Calc4} &360& 32& 118 &275\\
    2006& 5 &Other\tnotex{Calc5} &350& 432& 118 &275\\
    %\bottomrule
\end{longtable}  
\begin{tablenotes}
    \item Ref.\label{Calc1}
    \item Ref.\label{Calc2}
    \item Ref.\label{Calc3}
    \item Ref.\label{Calc4}
    \item Ref.\label{Calc5}
\end{tablenotes} 
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You redefine `tablenotes`, consequently its oprion `para` doesn't work anymore. You have two option (i) remove` your redefinition of `tablenotes` and use use `\item[a]`, `\item[b]` etc., (ii) correct your definition on the way, that it consider `inline` list.

Comment: how can i correct my definition

Comment: Difficult. I will not due this, rather stick with original definition of `tablenotes`. I'm not familiar with `threeparttable` internals, so I can't help you.

Comment: thanks @ Zarko .

Comment: See answer below, It may help you in redesign of your `tablenotes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, it the following can help you:

```
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate*}{1}
\makeatletter
\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\tnote{\alph*},
                     ref=\alph*,
                     itemsep=\z@,
                     topsep=\z@skip,
                     partopsep=\z@skip,
                     parsep=\z@,
                     itemindent=\z@,
                     labelindent=\tabcolsep,
                     labelsep=.8em,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     align=left,
                     before={\footnotesize}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Note, I didn't bother with your `tablenotes` formation, but you may try the following settings:

```
\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\tnote{\alph*}\ ,
                     before=\unskip{: }, itemjoin={{;\quad }}, itemjoin*={{, and }},
                     before={\footnotesize}
                     }
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: I tried with your settings, but the notes are still on 5 lines (i must use elsarticle package).

Comment: For test I use your MWE. where I only change `\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}` to `\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate*}{1}` (observe asterix).

Comment: Yes you are right, i forgot asterix. Now it works well, thank you very much.